# LLVM and visual studio .obj binary incompatibility

Tags: visual-c++, llvm, clang

Does anyone know if LLVM binary compatibility is planned for visual studio combiled .obj and static .lib files?
Right now I can only link LLVM made .obj files with dynamic libs that loads a DLL at runtime (compiled from visual studio).

While there probably is very small chances that binary compatibility will happen between the two compilers, does anybody know why it is so difficult achieving this between compilers for one platform?

Comment: The extent to which clang .o and other libs get linked at best in my practice is as much success as ld gets. Specific to my setup I'm using -m i386pep with ld. Unless llvm's lld surpasses ABI compatibility in future, imho best guess is this is the limitation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Neil already said, the compatibility includes stuff like calling convention, name mangling, etc. Though these two are the smallest possible problems. LLVM already knows about all windows-specific calling conventions (stdcall, fastcall, thiscall), this is why you can call stuff from .dll's.

If we speak about C++ code then the main problem is C++ ABI: vtable layout, rtti implementation, etc. clang follows Itanium C++ ABI (which gcc use, for example, among others), VCPP - doesn't and all these are undocumented, unfortunately. There is some work going in clang in this direction, so stuff might start to work apparently. Note that most probably some parts will never be covered, e.g. seh-based exception handling on win32, because it's patented.

Linking with pure C code worked for ages, so, you might workaround these C++ ABI-related issues via C stubs / wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from anything else, such as calling conventions, register usage etc, for C++ code to binary compatible the two compilers must use the same name-mangling scheme. These schemes are proprietory (so MS does not release the details if its scheme) and are in any case in a constant state of flux.

Comment: I found the documentation for Microsofts name mangling scheme (on Wikipedia even) so i don't believe that is the main cause. I haven't yet investigated if it is possible to change the mangling scheme with a commandline switch. I will check when i get home.

Comment: @Andos It isn't, and it is one of the main reasons. Wikipedia is not documentation.

Comment: name mangling is the smallest possible issue here, really. The main problem is C++ ABI compatibility.

Comment: @Anton Hence my introductory phrase - "Apart from anything else". And no, it's not "the smallest possible issue".

Comment: @Matthieu: MSVC doesn't have to use SEH for C++ exceptions. They have a table based implementation similar to DWARF.

Also, it's not Microsoft that has to allow it. It's whoever now owns the 32bit SEH patent from Borland.