# CORBA omniORB unable to get remote object after resolving name context

Tags: c++, corba, omniorb, nameservice

I have an IDL as below

```
module IClientServer {

  interface IClient 
  {
    void serverResponse(in string name, in string data);

    void start();

    void stop();

    void shutdown();

  };

  interface IServer 
  {

     // Server calls back to client just once in a
     // recursive call before returning.
     // void one_time(in CallBack cb, in string mesg);
    void DataFromX(in string name,in string data,in long lbytes,in short usg);

    void Authenticate(in IClient client, in string dataToNegotiate);

     // Shuts down the server.
    void shutdown();

  };
};
```

for which I generated proxy & skeleton using idl2cpp utility (onmiORB) and linked generated files to server & client app as suggested in the document

Then I started name service (omniNames) and added registry key omniORB\InitRef as suggested in documentation for the server & client apps to connect without using commandline arguments

**Below is the server code**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try 
    {
    int argc = 0;
        _BRDTRACE("Initializing....\n");
        CORBA::ORB_var orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, NULL);
//          cerr << "Initialized." << endl;

        CORBA::Object_var obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");
        _BRDTRACE("Resolved.\n");


        PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow(obj);
        _BRDTRACE("Narrowed..\n");

            // Obtain a reference to the object, and register it in
            // the naming service.
        server_i* myserver = new server_i();
//          cerr << "Constructed." << endl;

        obj = myserver->_this();
        _BRDTRACE("obj retrieved.\n");

        CORBA::String_var x;
        x = orb->object_to_string(obj);
        _BRDTRACE("obj to string.\n");

        if( !bindObjectToName(orb, obj) )
        {
//            cerr << "Failed to bind obj to name." << endl;
          throw;
        }

        _BRDTRACE("binded\n");
        myserver->_remove_ref();
//          cerr << "removed ref." << endl;

        PortableServer::POAManager_var pman = poa->the_POAManager();
        pman->activate();
        _BRDTRACE("activated.\n");

//          cerr << "Executing..." << endl;
        orb->run();
        _BRDTRACE("Terminated.\n");

        myserver->shutdown();
//          cerr << "Shutdown." << endl;

    }
    catch(CORBA::SystemException&) 
    {
        _BRDTRACE("Caught CORBA::SystemException.\n");
    }
    catch(CORBA::Exception&) {
        _BRDTRACE("Caught CORBA::Exception.\n");
    }
    catch(omniORB::fatalException&) 
    {
        _BRDTRACE("Caught omniORB::fatalException:\n");
//          cerr << "  file: " << fe.file() << endl;
//          cerr << "  line: " << fe.line() << endl;
//          cerr << "  mesg: " << fe.errmsg() << endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
        _BRDTRACE("Caught unknown exception.\n");
    }

}

static CORBA::Boolean
bindObjectToName(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb, CORBA::Object_ptr objref)
{
  CosNaming::NamingContext_var rootContext;

  try {
    // Obtain a reference to the root context of the Name service:
    CORBA::Object_var obj;
    obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

    // Narrow the reference returned.
    rootContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
    if( CORBA::is_nil(rootContext) ) {
      _BRDTRACE("Failed to narrow the root naming context.\n");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  catch(CORBA::ORB::InvalidName& ex) {
    // This should not happen!
    _BRDTRACE("Service required is invalid [does not exist].\n");
    return 0;
  }

  try {
    // Bind a context called "test" to the root context:

    CosNaming::Name contextName;
    contextName.length(1);
    contextName[0].id   = (const char*) "birdseye";       // string copied
    contextName[0].kind = (const char*) "collections_context"; // string copied
    // Note on kind: The kind field is used to indicate the type
    // of the object. This is to avoid conventions such as that used
    // by files (name.type -- e.g. test.ps = postscript etc.)

    //CosNaming::NamingContext_var testContext;
    try {
      // Bind the context to root.
      rootContext->bind(contextName, objref);
    }
    catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound& ex) {
      // If the context already exists, this exception will be raised.
      // In this case, just resolve the name and assign testContext
      // to the object returned:
      CORBA::Object_var obj;
      obj = rootContext->resolve(contextName);
      CosNaming::NamingContext_var testContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
      if( CORBA::is_nil(testContext) ) {
        _BRDTRACE("Failed to narrow naming context.\n");
        return 0;
      }
    }
  } catch(CORBA::COMM_FAILURE& ex) {
   _BRDTRACE("Caught system exception COMM_FAILURE -- unable to contact the naming service.\n");
    return 0;
  }
  catch(CORBA::SystemException&) {
    _BRDTRACE("Caught a CORBA::SystemException while using the naming service.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

**But the below code in the client side returns nil object after name
 context resolution. Not able to figure out the issue. Please help!**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CORBA::ORB_var orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv);
    CORBA::Object_var objRef = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
    CORBA::Object_var obj = getObjectReference(orb);
    IClientServer::IServer_var svr = IClientServer::IServer::_narrow(obj.in());
  if( CORBA::is_nil(svr) ) {    **//THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS**
 //   _BRDTRACE("cb_client: The server reference is nil!\n");
    return 0;
  }
    return 0;
}

static CORBA::Object_ptr
getObjectReference(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb)
{
  CosNaming::NamingContext_var rootContext;

  try {
    // Obtain a reference to the root context of the Name service:
    CORBA::Object_var obj;
    obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

    // Narrow the reference returned.
    rootContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
    if( CORBA::is_nil(rootContext) ) {
//      cerr << "Failed to narrow the root naming context." << endl;
      return CORBA::Object::_nil();
    }
  }
  catch(CORBA::ORB::InvalidName& ) {
    // This should not happen!
    return CORBA::Object::_nil();
  }
  // Create a name object, containing the name test/context:
  CosNaming::Name name;
  name.length(1);

  name[0].id   = (const char*) "birdseye";       // string copied
  name[0].kind = (const char*) "collections_context"; // string copied
  // Note on kind: The kind field is used to indicate the type
  // of the object. This is to avoid conventions such as that used
  // by files (name.type -- e.g. test.ps = postscript etc.)


  try {
    // Resolve the name to an object reference.
    return rootContext->resolve(name);
  }
  catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound& nf) {
  }
  catch(CORBA::COMM_FAILURE& ) {
  }
  catch(CORBA::SystemException&) {
  }

  return CORBA::Object::_nil();
}
```

**UPDATE-5PM:**
Infact the server side code also has same issue server->authenticate is never called due to nil reference.

Guess : Can there be an issue with proxy & stubs generated with idl2cpp tool?

**UPDATE-7:30PM**
The ambiguity on stubs not ok is also gone, the issue still persists after regenerating the stubs & rebuilding both client & server apps again

**UPDATE 3-31|11AM**
I am using omniORB 4.0.3 which is over 10 year old. This has worked great in earlier windows OS versions compiled with VC6, I doubt there is issue when recompiled on VS 2008. Just thinking of upgrade to ommiORB 4.2 released last year. Just clueless whatsoever...

**UPDATE 3-31|5:30PM**
Currently building omniORB4.2.1 source code. While I do this I still want to know if there is any issue linking the .lib files that are generated in older systems. In this case the omniORB .lib files I am using in Windows 7 is built on Windows XP, would that be an issue? Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439595/are-compiled-lib-files-interchangeable-for-different-versions-of-microsoft-visu) post could not answer, I have a old .lib that compiled & linked well without any issues & even the runtime it did not crash as well

**UPDATE 4-01|4:30PM**
Actually I noticed there is no server running, the server code I posted earlier is also client, I now updated real server code(the code which binds name to server obj). But the issue remains same even after this correction

Comment: So the `obj` variable returned from `getObjectReference` is not `nil`? You are ignoring the `CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound` exception so it would be `nil` if not found. It this is the issue, you can use the `nameclt` utility to examine what's in the naming service.

Comment: @pcarter Thanks for a glance, actually the control is not stepping into NotFound exception, I confirmed this with debugger. Actually the server code isnt actually the real server code. But even after running the real server code still left with the same issue. updated sever code in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue. There are 2 issues with the code 
issue 1 I already updated in question (missing server code) 
issue 2 is with name context binding..

**below is modified version of bindObjectToName in server**

```
static CORBA::Boolean
bindObjectToName(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb, CORBA::Object_ptr objref)
{
  CosNaming::NamingContext_var rootContext;

  try {
    // Obtain a reference to the root context of the Name service:
    CORBA::Object_var obj;
    obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

    // Narrow the reference returned.
    rootContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
    if( CORBA::is_nil(rootContext) ) {
//      cerr << "Failed to narrow the root naming context." << endl;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  catch(CORBA::ORB::InvalidName& ex) {
    // This should not happen!
  //  cerr << "Service required is invalid [does not exist]." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  try {
    // Bind a context called "test" to the root context:

    CosNaming::Name contextName;
    contextName.length(1);
    contextName[0].id   = (const char*) "birdsEYE";       // string copied
    contextName[0].kind = (const char*) "DataCollectionS"; // string copied
    // Note on kind: The kind field is used to indicate the type
    // of the object. This is to avoid conventions such as that used
    // by files (name.type -- e.g. test.ps = postscript etc.)

    CosNaming::NamingContext_var testContext;
    try {
      // Bind the context to root.
      testContext = rootContext->bind_new_context(contextName);
    }
    catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound& ex) {
      // If the context already exists, this exception will be raised.
      // In this case, just resolve the name and assign testContext
      // to the object returned:
      CORBA::Object_var obj;
      obj = rootContext->resolve(contextName);
      testContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
      if( CORBA::is_nil(testContext) ) {
    //    cerr << "Failed to narrow naming context." << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }

    // Bind sender :
    CosNaming::Name objectName;
    objectName.length(1);
    objectName[0].id   = (const char*) "clienT";   // string copied
    objectName[0].kind = (const char*) "sendeR"; // string copied

    try {
      testContext->bind(objectName, objref);
    }
    catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound& ex) {
      testContext->rebind(objectName, objref);
    }
    // Note: Using rebind() will overwrite any Object previously bound
    //       to /test/Echo with obj.
    //       Alternatively, bind() can be used, which will raise a
    //       CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound exception if the name
    //       supplied is already bound to an object.

    // Bind receiver :
    CosNaming::Name objectName2;
    objectName2.length(1);
    objectName2[0].id   = (const char*) "clienT";   // string copied
    objectName2[0].kind = (const char*) "receiveR"; // string copied

    try {
      testContext->bind(objectName2, objref);
    }
    catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound& ex) {
      testContext->rebind(objectName2, objref);
    }


    // Amendment: When using OrbixNames, it is necessary to first try bind
    // and then rebind, as rebind on it's own will throw a NotFoundexception if
    // the Name has not already been bound. [This is incorrect behaviour -
    // it should just bind].

  }
  catch(CORBA::COMM_FAILURE& ex) {
    //cerr << "Caught system exception COMM_FAILURE -- unable to contact the "
    //     << "naming service." << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  catch(CORBA::SystemException&) {
    //cerr << "Caught a CORBA::SystemException while using the naming service."
    // << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

**And below the modified getObjectReference in client code**
static CORBA::Object_ptr

```
getObjectReference(CORBA::ORB_ptr orb)
{
  CosNaming::NamingContext_var rootContext;

  try {
    // Obtain a reference to the root context of the Name service:
    CORBA::Object_var obj;
    obj = orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");

    // Narrow the reference returned.
    rootContext = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj);
    if( CORBA::is_nil(rootContext) ) {
//      cerr << "Failed to narrow the root naming context." << endl;
      return CORBA::Object::_nil();
    }
  }
  catch(CORBA::ORB::InvalidName& ex) {
    // This should not happen!
  //  cerr << "Service required is invalid [does not exist]." << endl;
    _BRDTRACE("getObjRef: service required is invalid.\n");
    exit(0);
    return CORBA::Object::_nil();
  }


  // Create a name object, containing the name test/context:
  CosNaming::Name name;
  name.length(2);

  name[0].id   = (const char*) "birdsEYE";       // string copied
  name[0].kind = (const char*) "DataCollectionS"; // string copied
  name[1].id   = (const char*) "clienT";
  name[1].kind = (const char*) "sendeR";
  // Note on kind: The kind field is used to indicate the type
  // of the object. This is to avoid conventions such as that used
  // by files (name.type -- e.g. test.ps = postscript etc.)


  try {
    // Resolve the name to an object reference.
    return rootContext->resolve(name);
  }
  catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::NotFound& ex) {
    // This exception is thrown if any of the components of the
    // path [contexts or the object] aren't found:
    //cerr << "Context not found." << endl;
    _BRDTRACE("getObjRef: context not found.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  catch(CORBA::COMM_FAILURE& ex) {
    //cerr << "Caught system exception COMM_FAILURE -- unable to contact the "
     //    << "naming service." << endl;
    _BRDTRACE("getObjRef: caught system exception COMM_FAILURE.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  catch(CORBA::SystemException&) {
    //cerr << "Caught a CORBA::SystemException while using the naming service."
     //<< endl;
    _BRDTRACE("getObjRef: caught system exception while using the name service.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  return CORBA::Object::_nil();
}
```